# Excel file with Multiple Sheets in Laravel-Excel 3.1 -> Import Original and Store + Store Individual sheets after cell validations

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel

Thanks for the reaching out to my question, but i have got a problem, I'm trying to Import an excel file with multiple sheets.

- Find sheets by some cell-value validation, like if on cell E7, i have a value, store this sheet as separate file. I'm doing mapping() for cell values, and then trying to use Excel::store to save each individual sheet separately. Can't receive any data for individual sheets
- Also store the original file. This works!

The issue is, i can't receive any data for storing individual-sheets as excel files, i can create the individual excel files, but no data is being received, or maybe i'm not using the right data-format mentioned on documentation.

Please also check the code. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public function mapping(): array
{
    return [
        'altafit_id'  => 'E7',
        'year'  => 'B3',
        'initial_month'  => 'B4',
        'final_month'  => 'B5',
    ];
}

public function model(array $row)
{
    // dd($row);
    $name = $row['altafit_id'];
    $year = $row['year'];
    $initial_month = $row['initial_month'];
    $final_month = $row['final_month'];
    $file_type = 'club';
    // dd(collect((object) $row));
    Excel::store(collect((object) $row), 'P&L_' . $name . '_' . $year . '_' . $initial_month . '_06' . ',clubs' . ',' . $initial_month . ',' . $final_month . '.' . 'xls', 'public');

    return new Files([
        //'user_id' =>  $row['user_id'],
        'file_name' => 'P&L_' . $name . '_' . $year . '_' . $initial_month . '_06' . ',clubs' . ',' . $initial_month . ',' . $final_month . '.' . 'xls',
        'file_type' => $file_type
    ]);
}
```

Already check the documentation, but doesn't work for me.
https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/getting-started/[image]